# Setting & Retrieving Cookies in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie in Laravel 4 which lasts for 30 days and then be able to retrieve it if the user comes back to the website within that period.

I follow the code for making the cookie:

```
Cookie::make('cookie_name', 'cookie_value, 1800)
```

I then try to retrieve it using a closure just for testing:

```
Route::get('test', function() {

    dd(Cookie::get('cookie_name'));
});
```

But it just returns NULL. I've read on the Laravel docs about returning them with a response but don't really understand this.

Surely it should just be a case of setting a cookie by name which then exists on a user's machine and you can then retrieve the cookie by that name if it exists?

Would really appreciate if someone could explain this!

Comment: please check the cookie value. and just try with `queue`.
`Cookie::queue('key', 'value', 'minutes');`

Comment: Ah yes, it returns the value when I use queue instead. So will this stay on the users machine for 1800 mins (30 days as above)?

Comment: Just tried closing/reopening the browser and it had gone back to null

Comment: If you would like to set a cookie before a response has been created, use the `Cookie::queue()` method. The cookie will automatically be attached to the final response from your application.

Comment: Ok thanks. But if I close/reopen my browser the value is no longer set? How do I get the cookie to stay on the users machine?

Comment: You can create cookies that last forever. `$cookie = Cookie::forever('name', 'value');`

Comment: Forgot to see the time on the queue cookie which is staying set now even after restarting machine. Make or forever wont set them though, not sure why but can just use queue instead. Thanks!